# Converting Typescript absolute paths to nodejs relative paths?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, npm, commonjs

I'm compiling typescript to es5 / commonjs format.  I'm using typescript's `tsconfig.json paths` property to specify a fixed root for `import statements.

So for example I might have a path configuration `@example: './src/'`.

After the *.ts files are compiled the the require statements will look something like:

```
require('@example/boo/foo');
```

I need to create a post processing script that considers the path of the current javascript file and the import path.

So for example if the javascript file having it's imports updated is located in `dist/foo/pitythefoo.js` and it imports exports from `dist/boo/boo.js` then the path `@example/boo/boo` has to be replaced with `../boo/boo`.

Now if `pitythefoo.js` was at the root of `dist` (`dist/pitythefoo.js` then the `@example` string would just be replaced with `./`.

So the basic algorithm seems to be:

If the file is at the root of `dist`, then replace `@example` with `./`.  If it's deeper, then count how deep and if it's for example two directories deep, then add the `../..` to move up to the root and then into the path where the importing module resource sits.  Sound reasonable?

So in general I was was thinking something like:

```
globby('dist/**/*.js'). //get the paths of all the js files
then(process); //read each file as a text file and perform the string replacement
               //Save the file using the original file name.


 function process(path:string) {
    const file = fs.readFileSync(path);
    //update require statements contents of file
    fs.writeFileSync(file,path);
 }
```

Does anyone know of a utility that function that can analyzes the import path length and the path of the current resources and generate the correct relative path for the `require()` statement?

It seems like it might be a fairly common pattern, so trying to avoid reinventing the wheel ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I've implemented a script that solves this for my project](https://github.com/fireflysemantics/validator/blob/master/createdist.js).  The goal was to be able to use the non relative paths, which we can do with Typescripts `paths` configuration option, and have the compiled ES5 / CommonJS output use relative paths such that the package could be published to NPM.  The link above has the github version and here it is the code:

```
    const fs = require("fs");
    const globby = require("globby");
    require("mkdirp").sync("dist");
    require("cpy")("package.json", "dist");
    const options = { overwrite: true };
    const rc = require("recursive-copy");
    rc("target/src/", "dist", options).then(() => {
      globby("./dist/**/*.js")
        .then(paths => {
          paths.forEach(update);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));

        globby("./dist/**/*.d.ts")
        .then(paths => {
          paths.forEach(update);
        })
        .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });

    function update(path) {
      count = (path.match(/\//g) || []).length;
      let replacement = "";
      if (count == 2) {
        replacement = "./";
      } else if (count > 2) {
        const size = count - 2;
        replacement = Array(size)
          .fill("../")
          .join("");
      } else {
        throw new Error("Invalid / count in path of file");
      }
      let js = fs.readFileSync(path, "utf8");
      js = js.replace(/@fs\//g, replacement);
      fs.writeFileSync(path, js);
    }
```